# Combining ternary operator and equality statements in ng-class

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ternary-operator, ng-class

I have an element:
`<div ng-class="a ? 'class1' : 'class2'"></div>`
I need to add another ng-class statement to it `ng-class="class3: b !== c"`.
How do I combine the ng-class statements together.
Neither `<div ng-class="{a ? 'class1' : 'class2, class3: b !== c"></div>` nor `<div ng-class="(a ? 'class1' : 'class2') + ' ' + (class3: b !== c)"></div>`
seem to work. Please advise.

Comment: This is not really the way you should use ng-class, still, you can cheat: ng-class="(a ? 'class1' : 'class2') + ' ' + (b !== c ? 'class3': '' )"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My preferred syntax for ng-class is the following, since it is explicit as to which classes you are adding, without using the ternary operator:

```
<div ng-class="{'class1' : a, 'class2' : !a, 'class3': b !== c }"></div>
```

If you want to use the ternary, you can do this:

```
<div ng-class="(a ? 'class1' : 'class2') + ' ' + (b !== c ? 'class3': '' )></div>
```

Your solutions didn't work because you tried to mix the 2 differents syntaxes (with and without curly brackets).

Comment: Thanks for your fast and concise answer. You're a lifesaver.

Answer (score 2):

i think you can do this without an ternary operator like this.

```
<div ng-class="{'class1' : a, 'class2' : !a, 'class3': b !== c }"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var app = angular.module('exApp', []);

app.controller('ctrl', function($scope){
$scope.a = 1;
$scope.c = 10;
$scope.b = 89;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<style>
.class1{
font-size:18px;
}
.class2{
color:orange;
}
.class3{
color:blue;
}
</style>
<body ng-app="exApp" ng-controller="ctrl">
<p ng-class="a ? 'class1' : 'class2'">Hi..Used Ternary Operator</p>
<p ng-class="{'class3': b !== c, 'class1' : !a, 'class2':a, }">Hi!...Without Ternary Operator</p>
</body>
```

```
ng-class=" {className1: checkIftrue, className2: otherCondition}"
```

Comment: Thanks for the example.  What if you need multiple uses on the ternary example such as violations: node.violation?  ng-class="a ? 'class1' : 'class2, {violations: node.violation}'" obviously would not work